# Proving a first-passage time identity

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

Let $(X_0, X_1, ...)$ be an irreducible, recurrent Markov chain and $T_k$ be the first-passage time to $k\in S$, i.e. $T_k = \inf\{n\geq1 : X_n = k\}$.

My aim is to show that, for $i \in S$,
$$\Sigma_{r=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}_k(X_r=i, T_k \geq r+1)=\Sigma_{m=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}_k(X_m=i,T_k\geq m).$$
For context, see Probability (Grimmett), Page 233. I began by separately considering the cases where $i=k$ and $i \neq k$. For the latter case, we see the first summands are zero and the rest are equivalent. For the former, we have the first summand as
$$\mathbb{P}_k(X_0=k, T_k \geq 1)= \mathbb{P}_k(X_1=k,T_k\geq 1)=1.$$
For the other summands, the terms from the first summation are zero, since $X_r = k$ implies that $T_k \leq r$ when $r>0$. Hence it remains to show that 
$$\mathbb{P}_k(X_m=k,T_k\geq m)=0$$
for all $m >1$. I'm having a hard time doing this. Since $X_m = k$ implies that $T_k \leq m$, we have 
$$\mathbb{P}_k(X_m=k,T_k\geq m)= \mathbb{P}_k(X_m=k,T_k= m).$$
Why is this zero?

Comment: Consider $i\neq k$, where $\mathbb P_k(X_r=i, T_k\geq r+1)=\mathbb P_k(X_r=i, T_k\geq r)$ for $r\geq 1$ and $\mathbb P_k(X_0=i, T_k\geq 1)=1$, which means the LHS of your equation is 1 more than the RHS. Could you please check for that? Btw, I don’t find this equation in Page 233 in Grimmett’s book.

Comment: @FengShao $\mathbb{P}_k$ denotes the probability given that $X_0 = k$, so $\mathbb{P}_k(X_0=i, T_k\geq 1)=\mathbb P(X_0=i, T_k\geq 1| X_0 = k)=0$ for $i \neq k$? It's the second edition of the book if that makes any difference. The equation is implicit in the book but he wrote it out explicitly in a lecture

Comment: I finally figure it out. At first time I thought it was Grimmett's *Probability and Random Processes*. Thanks for your explanation for my mistake in last comment. I'll write an short answer.

Comment: @FengShao Thank you. I've realised that I was for some reason confusing $\mathbb{P}_k(X_m=k,T_k\geq m)$ with $\mathbb{P}_k(T_k\geq m | X_m=k)$. I must have been tired!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case $i\neq k$ is clear as the OP said.

For the case $i=k$, $\mathbb P_k(X_r=k, T_k\geq r+1)=0$ for $r\geq 1$ but for $r=0$ we have $\mathbb P_k(X_0=k, T_k\geq 1)=1.$ Finally, we have 
\begin{aligned}
RHS&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\mathbb P_k(X_m=k, T_k\geq m)\\&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty P_k(X_m=k, T_k=m)\\&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty P_k( T_k=m)\\&=1=LHS.
\end{aligned}
The proof is complete now.